# Transparent logical filter on entities - App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nodes

i'm not sure i can easily do this but i need to automatically add a filter on a field for every query related to my model. I've added a boolean property "active" to my model called Node.

For example

```
Node.query()
```

should return every node with the field Node.active set to True and ignore nodes with the active field set to false, without any other instructions.

Is it possible to override the function in any way or something similar? I'm not really good with neither python nor with app engine so i'm not sure i can actually do this.

Comment: You certainly could override the `query` method to act as you described, but that would prevent you from making a query _without_ the filter. Tim's answer makes more sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class method to your Node class that does the query for you, then always use that.  e.g.

```
class Node(db.Model):
   # some properties and stuff

   @classmethod
   def active_nodes(cls):
       return cls.all().filter('active = ',True)
```

Then always use Node.active_nodes()
This is forms part of your formal api that you always use.  I use the approach extensively rather than writing the same (and often more complex query) all over the place.

Comment: this is a smart solution and for now i will settle with this. I think it's more practical even if i'm still interested in doing what i wrote in my question, mainly to understand better python and ndb. Anyway this solution is fine enough to solve the problem.